# Data structure to check if multiple periods overlap

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a class `Period` that is represented by `start` and `end` dates, where `end` is after `start`. I need to write a function to check if periods overlap.

The straightforward approach is to check every period with every other period. Is there a way to introduce a data structure that will perform faster?

```
class Period {
      LocalDateTime start;
      LocalDateTime end;
}
 

boolean isOverlap(Set<Period> periods) {
    // TODO put the code here
}
```

`isOverlap` should return `true` when at least two of the periods overlap.

Comment: Can you please clarify when `isOverlap` should return true? Should this happen when all the periods are overlapping all the other periods?

Comment: I would implement `Comparable` interface. Then, with a `TreeSet` you can compare in order.

Comment: @Oboe Exactly how would you implement `compareTo` for a pair of dates or a pair of moments? Is Halloween to Christmas bigger or smaller than November 1 to November 20?

Comment: @Basil Bourque That depends of what you want to achieve. For this specific case I would implement it the same way the `Stream` is sorted in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking every period against every other period will have an O(n<sup>2</sup>) time complexity. Instead, I'd sort them by start and end times and then iterate over the list. This way, a period can only overlap the periods directly before and after it (or multiple subsequent ones before or after it - but that's inconsequential, since you're looking for a single overlap to return `true`). You can iterate over the list and check this. The total cost of this algorithm would be the cost of the sorting, O(nlog(n)):

```
boolean isOverlap(Set<Period> periods) {
    List<Period> sorted =
        periods.stream()
               .sorted(Comparator.comparing((Period p) -> p.start)
                                 .thenComparing(p -> p.end))
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
    for (int i = 0; i < sorted.size() - 1; ++i) {
        if (sorted.get(i).end.compareTo(sorted.get(i + 1).start) > 0) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I guess it should ` > 0` to make it work.

Comment: @yu.pitomets arg, yeah, that's correct. A momentary lapse in concentration there, sorry about that. Thanks for noticing! Edited and fixed.